# Application of the heat equation, PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> A solid, homogeneous object occupies the region $D\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$, and is completely insulated. Its initial temperature is given by $u(x,0) = \phi(x)$, for some function $\phi$. So $u$ satisfies the heat equation $u_t = k\Delta u$ with boundary condition $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = 0$ on $\partial D$. After a long time, the object reaches a steady, uniform temperature. In terms of $f$, what is this temperature?

I normally don't post a question without at least some attempt but I have no idea how to start this. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is $f$?  Do you mean $\phi$?

Comment: The region D isn't defined anywhere. Is it just everything above the x-axis?

Comment: @Kaynex, The OP seems to suggest that it's in $\mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the boundary condition, we have
$$
\oint_{\partial D} \boldsymbol\nabla u \cdot d\mathbf{A} = \oint_{\partial D}\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} dA = 0.
$$
From the divergence theorem, we have
$$
\oint_{\partial D} \boldsymbol\nabla u \cdot d\mathbf{A} = \int_D\nabla^2u \,dV = \int_D\frac{1}{k}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} dV = \frac{d}{dt}\int_D\frac{u}{k}\,dV
$$
assuming $k$ is constant in time (if it is also constant in space, you can pull it out of the integral entirely). In other words
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int_D \frac{u}{k}\, dV = 0
$$
This should not be surprising, as heat conduction conserves energy and the boundary condition says there's no energy outflow from $D$. From here I think you can get the answer.

EDIT: So continuing from here, we have that the integral in the final state must equal the integral in the initial state. Thus,
$$
\int\frac{u(\mathbf{x},0)}{k}dV = \int_D\frac{\phi(\mathbf{x})}{k}dV = \int_D\frac{u(\mathbf{x},\infty)}{k}dV = \int_D\frac{T}{k}dV = T\int_D\frac{dV}{k}.
$$
So
$$
T = \frac{\int_D \frac{\phi(\mathbf{x})}{k}dV}{\int_D\frac{dV}{k}}
$$
If $k$ is constant in space, we can multiply the top and bottom by $k$ to get
$$
T = \frac{\int_D \phi(\mathbf{x}) dV}{\int_D dV} = \frac{1}{V}\int_D\phi(\mathbf{x})dV
$$
where $V$ is the volume of $D$.

This is as far as you can go without knowing the actual function $\phi(\mathbf{x})$.

Comment: I am not sure where to go from where you started, I understand your work. But what exactly to I need to do from here?

Comment: If the time derivative of a quantity is zero, that means its initial value is equal to its final value. So calculate the value of the integral in the initial state where $u = \phi(\mathbf{x})$ and in the final state where $u = T$, then set them equal to each other and solve for T.

Comment: I am sorry I am a bit slow at the moment. Could you re-edit to show me how to calculate the integral in the initial state where $u = \phi(x)$?

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: @SharatVChandrasekhar I am not sure how that shows me how to calculate the value of the integral in the inital state where $u = \phi(x)$?

Comment: Well, you'll need to provide a functional form for $\phi(x)$, a coordinate system and define your boundary $\partial D$

Comment: Thank you for submitting an entire solution. I am using the book, Partial Differential Equations by Walter A. Strauss. But reading the first chapter I don't see how we would have been able to answer this question. Are there any other books I should consider reading?

Comment: Many times in an introductory chapter, you're not actually being asked to come up with a specific detailed solution. It appears that the intent of the problem in Strauss' book is to make sure that you've grasped the basic conservation laws and understood how you would - given actual problem data which is not present here - calculate the actual temperature.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59465/discussion-between-sharat-v-chandrasekhar-and-scooby).

Answer (score 1):

If the object is completely insulated, then there is no loss of thermal energy in the system and so if the thermal capacity ($\rho c_p$) of the object is spatially invariant, then the equilibrium temperature will be

$$
u_{\text{eq}} = \frac{1}{V}\int_V\phi({\bf x})\text dv
$$

Comment: If you're trying to perform an actual set of calculations, then you would need to pay careful attention to a possible singularity at $t=0$ if $\phi({\bf x}), {\bf x} \in \partial D$ does not satisfy the $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=0$ condition.

Comment: Could you post a detailed solution I am still having a hard time with this one